# How to prevent duplicate records from insert to my table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
+-----+--------------+--------+-----------+
| id  |     a_no     | status | req_date  |
+-----+--------------+--------+-----------+
|   1 | 6019-6039120 |    0   |2015-03-01 |  
|   2 | 6019-6039120 |    0   |2015-03-01 |
|   4 | 6019-6039120 |    0   |2015-03-02 |
|   5 | 6019-6039121 |    0   |2015-03-02 |
|   6 | 6019-6039134 |    0   |2015-03-02 |
|   7 | 6019-6039134 |    0   |2015-03-02 |
|   8 | 6019-6039120 |    0   |2015-03-03 |
|   9 | 6019-6039129 |    0   |2015-03-03 |
|  10 | 6019-6039145 |    0   |2015-03-04 |
|  11 | 6019-6039167 |    0   |2015-03-04 |
+-----+--------------+--------+-----------+
```

This is my table structure, as you can see `id=1 and id=2` have a same data. How to prevent the same data to insert into my table?

Comment: This is a good source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a unique constraint/index:

```
create unique index idx_table_3 on table(a_no, status, req_date);
```

This will prevent duplicates in the table.  An attempt to insert duplicates will result in an error.